# Change Active Directory in Samba share server

Tags: active-directory, samba, domain-controller, migration

I have the next scenenario:

- Legacy Windows 2k Server as PDC (Primary domain controller) called A
- Samba share server with some resources connected by winbind with A
- Clean Installation of Zentyal 4.0 Server (Active Directory role) called B

(Users of the domain can access to Samba shares)

Now, I want to migrate all the objects in A to B with the ADMT tool (Microsoft things) ,it works because I've tested it and I've migrated some objects to the Zentyal server...

But the point is, how can I change the Active Directory of the Samba share (from A to B) without modify all the permissions in the filesystem of the samba share server?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking:

> how can I change the Active Directory of the Samba share (from A to
>   B) without modify all the permissions in the filesystem of the samba
>   share server?

Isn't possible.  The new AD domain will need to be referenced.  You'll have to replace the permissions on the existing SAMBA server with permissions for the new domain manually.  There's not a "migration" for the ACLs themselves in this scenario.  You could potentially create a complex script...something that reads the permissions ACL for "DOMAIN_A\user1" and replaces it with "DOMAIN_B\user1" but it isn't something that we can easily create for you here and could be potentially a nightmare over manual ACL replacements.  This could be a potentially good time to work on cleaning up ACLs as well.

Comment: Then,probably I have to do a script that chown all the permissions in my shares?

Comment: It would be beyond just chown though.  You'd need to re-establish both the share permissions and the file/folder level permissions for the new domain somehow.  Manually it can be done.  Scripting it...possibly if the permissions are fairly simple.  This is also why at least on a Windows server it can make sense to use local groups with domain groups embedded in those local groups and then the local groups having ACLs.  That way the embedded groups inside the local group can be changed and you don't have to modify the ACLs at all.

Comment: Ok...more difficult than I though,maybe with **winbind** I can change the Internals UID and GID of the users, you know something about that?

Comment: Sorry, that's not something I'm familiar with.  I don't use SAMBA in my environments.